# How to set shortcut key to change view mode of service window to window in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

How to set shortcut key to change view mode of service window to window in intellij?

Because a lot of logs are taken, the service window is usually closed, but whenever necessary, the view mode is changed to window and used.

However, it is inconvenient to enter the menu and change the view mode to window.

I wonder how to change the view mode of the service window to window with a shortcut key.

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add showrtucs to

- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Keymap | All Actions | Other | Tool Windows View Modes | **Dock Pinned**
- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Keymap | All Actions | Other | Tool Windows View Modes | **Window**

modes:

[image]

[image]

and use these shortcuts when the tool window is focused to toggle between Windowed and Pinned modes.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any shortcut to do that, you have to explicitly click the small gear button and then change the view mode.

Check [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-modes.html) and [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tool-windows.html#bars_and_buttons).